# AspectJ LTW in eclipse - Pointcut does not work with static method

Tags: java, aspectj, static-methods

I have an Aspect class, which defines one point-cut expression as below

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.vg.pw.tasks.shared.*.executeTasks(..))")
public void myTraceCall() {}
```

where the executeTasks() method is static. If the method is made to non-static, the method body is executed on every call of `executeTasks()`. Why is my pointcut not effective on static methods?

I'm using LTW and not spring.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried out your pointcut expression and it works on both static and non-static methods just as it should. I used AspectJ weaver 1.8.7. Try adding `-showWeaveInfo` and `-verbose` to your aop.xml for debug info on LTW.

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-showWeaveInfo -verbose">
        <include within="q35218146..*" />
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="q35218146.Aspect35218146"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

It should give you output on stderr similar to this:

```
[AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void q35218146.
Test35218146.executeTasks())' in Type 'q35218146.Test35218146' (Test35218146.java:6) 
advised by before advice from 'q35218146.Aspect35218146' (Aspect35218146.java)
```

Comment: @Kris: I agree, it has to work on both statics and non-statics unless you also changed another factor such as (sub-)package name or method visibility. If it does not, please show a reproduceable [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Forgot to add `-verbose` to weaver options. I edited my answer to include that option too.