# Is it possible to instrument classess from java with aspectj?

Tags: java, android, aspectj, execution

Is it possible to instrument classes of the java.* packages?

I would like to use exécution() inside of call()

Thanks

Comment: You might want to see a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36121235/2699901) and the comments on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337164/2699901).

Comment: thanks you but when i add rt.jar to dependecy the compilation was failed